# Is it in any way possible to work with reals modulo integer values?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm working with a strange and perhaps (mathematically) nonsensical realm.

I'd like to know if we can work with $\mathbb{R}/ \mathbb{Z}$.

For example, if we take $(\pi \bmod 3)$ we get $(\pi - 3)$.

I'm wondering if I always end up with the same equivalence class modulo 3 if I truncate the reals in this way.

In general, I'd like to know if I can work this way modulo any integer.  **I want to know if this will work for addition, subtraction and multiplication.**

Comment: This might be of interest:

http://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/01/04/the-reals-mod-the-integers-are-a-group/

Comment: Addition and subtraction of reals will be well defined modulo integers. Multiplication will not be (in the following sense): $1.4$ and $0.4$ are in the same coset of the integers, but if you square them, the results won't be:
$$1.4^2=1.96,\qquad 0.4^2=0.16$$
The same thing happens with other pairs of reals. When multiplication is out, so will division.

In the language of abstract algebra: $\mathbb{Z}$ is a (normal) subgroup of the additive group of reals, but it is not an ideal of the ring of reals.

Comment: Another example, $\frac{1}{2} \sim \frac{3}{2}$, but $\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{8} \not\sim \frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{4} = \frac{3}{8}$.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexamples.  I will still try to find a way to get this to work...

Comment: Note that working in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ does not allow you to do "mod $3$". To do this, you should look at $\mathbb{R}/3\mathbb{Z}$ (which happens to be isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ as abelian groups).

Comment: $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ is indeed a group under addition, isomorphic to the [cirlce group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_group) $\Bbb T$. In particular, this means that it is closed under addition and subtraction.

Comment: If it were closed under all ring operations (i.e. a ring *congruence*) then multiplying $\rm\: 1\equiv 0\:$ times $\rm\: r\equiv r\:$ yields $\rm\:r \equiv 0.\:$ Or, equivalently the ideal $\rm\:I = \{ r\,:\, r\equiv 0\}\:$ contains $\,1,$ so $\rm\:I = \Bbb R.$ Thus, as a ring quotient $\rm\:\Bbb R/\Bbb Z \cong 0.\:$ But, as groups, the quotient is nontrivial. It is known as the [circle or torus group.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_group)

Answer (score 7):

$\mathbb Z$ is a normal subgroup of $\mathbb R$ (as a group under addition), so the quotient group $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ makes sense in the usual way in group theory.

$\mathbb Z$ is not an ideal of $\mathbb R$ (as a ring with addition and multiplication), so $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ does not make sense in the usual way in ring theory.

Comment: It *does* make sense as a ring, since the intended denotation of $\rm\,\Bbb Z\:$ is the ideal *generated* by $\rm\,\Bbb Z.\:$ Therefore $\rm\:R/\Bbb Z\:$ denotes $\rm\:R/\Bbb ZR \cong R/R \cong 0,\:$ just as $\rm\:R/2\:$ denotes $\rm\:R/2R.\:$ Generally, if one want to force some equalities to be true in an equational algebra (variety) such as groups, rings, etc. then one works in the algebra modulo the congruence *generated* by those equalities.